# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'F' python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small python code that prints out a sum of data provided by a user. More specifically I need the code to be able to calculate it when the number of data is not known in advance. To achieve that I need the code to recognize that the user did not indicate the size of the list and to know what is the last entry to be included by typing in "F". The problem I encountered with my code (see below) is that when I use "F" instead of "-1" the code crashes with the following message "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'F' python". Can anyone help me to understand what am I doing wrong, so I can fix it.

```
numberList = []
count = int(input("Enter the list size :"))
stopList = False
F = -1
mysum = 0
num = 0
if count >= 0:
    for i in range(0, count):
        item = int(input("Enter number :"))
        numberList.append(item)
        mysum = sum(numberList)
print("The sum is", mysum)
if count < 0:
    while stopList is False:
        nextnum = float(input("Enter number :"))
        if nextnum == F:
            stopList = True
        if stopList is False:
            num += 1
            mysum += nextnum
    print("The sum is", mysum)
```

Comment: You need to separate the `float` conversion and first check `if nextnum == 'F'`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Tomerikoo but I don't understand what do you mean by "separate the float conversion" could you expand on it.

Comment: First do `nextnum = input()` then check `if nextnum == 'F'` and only then `nextnum = float(nextnum)`

Comment: What do/don't you understand from the error message? Have you tried walking through the execution of the program?

Comment: @Tomerikoo unfortunately it didn't work:

Comment: if count < 0:
    while stopList is False:
        nextnum = input("Enter number :")
        if nextnum == 'F':
            nextnum = float(nextnum)
            stopList = True
        if stopList is False:
            num += 1
            mysum += nextnum
    print("The sum is", mysum)

Comment: gives "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: @AMC In order to make "F" to be the sentinel  it has to be converted into a float (I guess) but I don't know how to do it. I tried suggestion provided by Tomerikoo but as I wrote above it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will address only the problematic part of your code, which is everything after `if count < 0:`.

You should first take the input as-is and check if it is `'F'` and only then convert if to float, if necessary:

```py
while stopList is False:
    nextnum = input("Enter number :")
    if nextnum == 'F':
        stopList = True
    if stopList is False:
        num += 1
        mysum += float(nextnum)
print("The sum is", mysum)
```

As a side note, don't use the condition like this for the loop, I would use it like that:

```py
while True:
    nextnum = input("Enter number :")
    if nextnum == 'F':
        break

    num += 1
    mysum += float(nextnum)

print("The sum is", mysum)
```

Comment: This solve my problem, thank you so much for your help and the suggestion @Tomerikoo